# elasticsearch context suggester stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest

Is there a way to analyze a field that is passed to the context suggester?
If, say, I have this in my mapping:

```
mappings: {
    myitem: {
        title: {type: 'string'},
        content: {type: 'string'},
        user: {type: 'string', index: 'not_analyzed'},
        suggest_field: {
            type: 'completion',
            payloads: false,
            context: {
                user: {
                    type: 'category',
                    path: 'user'
                },
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I index this doc:

```
POST /myindex/myitem/1
{
    title: "The Post Title",
    content: ...,
    user: 123,
    suggest_field: {
        input: "The Post Title",
        context: {
            user: 123
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to analyze the input first, split it into separate words, run it through lowercase and stop words filters so that the context suggester actually gets

```
    suggest_field: {
        input: ["post", "title"],
        context: {
            user: 123
        }
    }
```

I know I can pass an array into the suggest field but I would like to avoid lowercasing the text, splitting it, running the stop words filter in my application, before passing to ES. If possible, I would rather ES do this for me. I did try adding an index_analyzer to the field mapping but that didn't seem to achieve anything.

OR, is there another way to get autocomplete suggestions for words?

Comment: Here is another way you can go about it, with ngrams (then you can do all the analysis you want), though it's a bit more involved: http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams

Comment: Having said that, I think there is a way to do what you want with completion suggest too (we also did a blog post about that: http://blog.qbox.io/quick-and-dirty-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-completion-suggest). I'll see if I can make what you're trying work.

Comment: Sloan, that article is very good and it helped me a lot when I was starting with ES. But, as the article says: "typing "disn" should return results containing "Disney"". I don't want "results containing "disney". I want "Disney", just that! I don't care which result it belongs to.

Comment: Have you tried using terms aggregations (or facets)?

Comment: Hmm,  no. Didn't even know there was such a thing! Let me check and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to help. Running the terms aggregation on the title returned "of", "the", "for", "in",... as the most used terms. Not useful as this is exactly what I am trying to remove. There doesn't seem to be a way to run an analyzer with aggregations either, is there?

Comment: Actually, yes. I think you can solve that problem with the stopwords token filter. I'll see if I can cook something up in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so this is pretty involved, but I think it does what you want, more or less. I'm not going to explain the whole thing, because that would take quite a bit of time. However, I will say that I started with [this blog post](http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams) and added a [stop token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html). The `"title"` field has sub-fields (what used to be called a [multi_field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html)) that use different analyzers, or none. The query contains a couple of [terms aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html). Also notice that the aggregations results are filtered by the match query to only return results relevant to the text query.

Here is the index setup (spend some time looking through this; if you have specific questions I will try to answer them but I encourage you to go through the blog post first):

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0,
      "analysis": {
         "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
               "type": "nGram",
               "min_gram": 2,
               "max_gram": 20,
               "token_chars": [
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            },
            "stop_filter": {
               "type": "stop"
            }
         },
         "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "stop_filter",
                  "nGram_filter"
               ]
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "stop_filter"
               ]
            },
            "stopword_only_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "asciifolding",
                  "stop_filter"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "doc": {
         "properties": {
            "title": {
               "type": "string",
               "index_analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  },
                  "stopword_only": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "stopword_only_analyzer"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I added a few docs:

```
PUT /test_index/_bulk
{"index": {"_index":"test_index", "_type":"doc", "_id":1}}
{"title": "The Lion King"}
{"index": {"_index":"test_index", "_type":"doc", "_id":2}}
{"title": "Beauty and the Beast"}
{"index": {"_index":"test_index", "_type":"doc", "_id":3}}
{"title": "Alladin"}
{"index": {"_index":"test_index", "_type":"doc", "_id":4}}
{"title": "The Little Mermaid"}
{"index": {"_index":"test_index", "_type":"doc", "_id":5}}
{"title": "Lady and the Tramp"}
```

Now I can search the documents with word prefixes if I want (or the full words, capitalized or not), and use aggregations to return both the intact titles of the matching documents, as well as intact (non-lowercased) words, minus the stopwords:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
    "query": {
      "match": {
         "title": {
            "query": "mer king",
            "operator": "or"
         }
      }
   }, 
    "aggs": {
        "word_tokens": {
            "terms": { "field": "title.stopword_only" }
        },
        "intact_titles": {
            "terms": { "field": "title.raw" }
        }
    }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 2,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "intact_titles": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "The Lion King",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "The Little Mermaid",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      },
      "word_tokens": {
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
         "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "The",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "King",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Lion",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Little",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Mermaid",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Notice that `"The"` gets returned. This seems to be because the default `_english_` stopwords only contain `"the"`. I didn't immediately find a way around this.

Here is the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/2fbb8a16b2cd35370f5d5944aa9ea7381544be79

Let me know if that helps you solve your problem.

Comment: "The" vs. "the" is not a problem as I can lowercase in stopword_only_analyzer. The problem is that for "kin" it returns lion (besides king, which is good). Being needed for autocompletion, I need just kin* words. Same for "merm" - it returns little too and I need just mermaid. For now I am doing this in 2 passes: first I send the text to /test_index/_analyze and get the tokens back then save the tokens as the suggester input array. While this works, I would love to do it in 1 single pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a analyzer which does this for you.

If you follow the tutorial called [you complete me](https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me), there is a section about stopwords.

There is a change in how elasticsearch works after this article was written. The `standard` analyzer no logner does stopword removal, so you need to use the `stop` analyzer in stead.

### The mapping

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:9200/hotels
curl -X PUT localhost:9200/hotels -d '
{
  "mappings": {
    "hotel" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : { "type" : "string" },
        "city" : { "type" : "string" },
        "name_suggest" : {
          "type" :            "completion",
          "index_analyzer" :  "stop",//NOTE HERE THE DIFFERENCE 
          "search_analyzer" : "stop",//FROM THE ARTICELE!!
          "preserve_position_increments": false,
          "preserve_separators": false
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}'
```

### Getting suggestion

```
curl -X POST localhost:9200/hotels/_suggest -d '
{
  "hotels" : {
    "text" : "m",
    "completion" : {
      "field" : "name_suggest"
    }
  }
}'
```

Hope this helps. I have spent a long time looking for this answer myself.